# Ubuntu gone wrong, because of using mv /*

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command

After using this command

```
 root@localhost:/var/www/google# mv /* ./
    mv /* ./
    mv: cannot move ?dev?to ?/dev? Device or resource busy
    mv: cannot move ?proc?to ?/proc? Device or resource busy
    mv: cannot move ?run?to ?/run? Device or resource busy
    mv: cannot move ?sys?to ?/sys? Device or resource busy
    mv: cannot move ?var?to a subdirectory of itself, ?/var?
```

Every command is going wrong.
 After that, I want to zip my files as backup and it gets wrong.
 Somebody help me, thank you .
 I want to  restore the system normally.
 If that not, how to zip it with some zip tools?

Comment: mv is move (rename) not zip, neither has anything to do with back up.

Comment: I'm just gonna go ahead and say: Your system is probably screwed at this point. I would just get started re-installing. Also, this is off-topic here.

Comment: Are you running as root or as an ordinary user? If you're running as root, you may be hosed. At the least, you've potentially broken your system horrendously. Don't run as root until you're sure you know what you're doing. You may be forced to reinstall from scratch. The extent of the problem does depend on the current directory when you executed the command — if it was `/`, then you were trying to move files and directories to their original location, but you can't do that with mount points (but you've probably not broken anything, even as root). Also, why all the question marks? They're odd!

Comment: i excueted command in this directory:: root@localhost:/var/www/google#

Comment: i can't find anything in var/www/google/  though i use that command

Comment: You've moved your kernel into a subdirectory; don't reboot.  You've also moved all your commands into subdirectories (so there is no `/bin` any more, nor a `/usr/bin` nor `/sbin`, etc).

Comment: You screwed up the system *real* good. You just (tried to) remove everything and stash it into wherever the backup was supposed to go. That probably tripped over itself after removing some critical piece of the system. I just have to say that this is the first time I see this. Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the comments, you were running as root and the current directory was `/var/www/google` when you ran the command:

```
mv /* ./
```

This has moved everything movable from `/` to `/var/www/google`.  One side effect is that the commands that normally live in `/bin` are now in `/var/www/google/bin` and those that live in `/usr/bin` are now in `/var/www/google/usr/bin`.

## Do not reboot.  Do not log out.

If you do, you will have to reinstall from scratch.

Temporarily, you can do:

```
PATH=/var/www/google/bin:/var/www/google/usr/bin:$PATH
cd /var/www/google
mv * /
```

These steps undo the primary damage (you should be able to reboot after this, but don't).

You then need to replace the directories that are now in `/` but that should be in `/var/www/google` back in the correct place.

You should create a new terminal session and check that your system is working sanely (do not close the open terminal until you've demonstrated that all is OK again).

Don't work as root unless you have to, and only for the minimum time necessary (one command at a time?).

If any of this fails, you should probably assume that a reinstall will be necessary.  Or take the machine to someone who has the experience to help you fix the problems.  There are endless things that could go wrong.  Mercifully for you, the `/dev` directory was not moved; that avoids a lot of problems.  However, the `/etc` directory was moved; commands could get upset about that.

Comment: mv command cannot excutes ::::::mv: command not found
,i think i should reinstall.but how to backup, i should backup it.but  tar/zip command is invalid and missing. anyway to backup? i use vps,should download backup before reinstaller

Comment: OK: same 'cannot find' message?  Try `hash -r` before doing the command.  Or try `/var/www/google/bin/mv * /` specifying the command path in full.  If that doesn't work, then life is about to get tricky.

Comment: You can't backup; none of the commands you need are readily available where you need them.  That's what 'reinstall from scratch' means.  You may be lucky and be able to 'upgrade' and stuff will be kicking around, but it is all a big mess.  It is also stuff that is more easily managed with hands on the machine — debugging from a distance is going to be painful.

Comment: If the commands are missing, you're stuck with using what's built into the shell until you find them.  Does the directory `/var/www/google/bin` exist?  Can you `cd` to it?  If not, you'll need to find it, which will be painful.  You can run `echo *` to see a list of the names in the current directory.  You can then try `cd`ing to relevant directories; it is hard to say what is going to be relevant.  Are you sure you were in exactly `/var/www/google` rather than in some directory under there?  It begins to sound as if you were not in the directory you thought you were in.

Comment: i can cd,and can login via sftp.the files are all moved to here.

Comment: `cd` is a built-in; the shell doesn't hunt for it via PATH.  You're lucky that you can `sftp` into the machine from elsewhere; I guess that daemon hasn't yet run into problems.  You've undoubtedly made a mess.  You mentioned 'vps' — what does that mean; 'virtual private server'?  You need to find where you moved your programs to, so you can move them back. Check in `/var/www` (`cd /var/www; echo *`), and in subdirectories under `/var/www/google` since it appears that you were not in `/var/www/google` when you did the damage.

Answer (score 1):

try to revert it

```
cd /var/www/google
mv ./* /
```

Good Luck

PD to zip:

```
zip archive.zip /path/to/zip/*
```

### EDIT

```
/var/www/google/bin/mv /var/www/google/* /
```

Comment: can't excute,notice:   -bash: /bin/mv: No such file or directory

Comment: See my answer: you will have to run `/var/www/google/bin/mv` as the command name, typing the path out in full.

Comment: Then try chroot /var/www/google first.. or do what @JonathanLeffler says.

Comment: i do as you say,still given:-bash: /var/www/google/bin/mv: No such file or directory